# Zend View Helper strange issue

Tags: zend-framework, view, helper, base-url

I have been working on a zend framework project on localhost (OS: Snow Leopard) and when I uploaded the files on the hosting server (shared hosting) I got some errors about a view helper i was using there.

More specifically:
The project structure is like this: ( i ommited some irrelevant subfolders and the numbers in the paranthesis is just for reference in here, it is not included in the folder name in the project)

```
application
-configs
-controllers
-layouts
--scripts
-models
-modules
--admin
---controllers
---models
---views(2)
----filters
----helpers(2)
----scripts
-views(1)
--helpers(1)
--scripts
library
public
```

In the helpers(1) folder i have a view helper, BaseURL.php:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_BaseURL
{
    function baseURL()
    {
        $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        return $fc->getBaseUrl();
    }
}
```

I use it, for example , in the layout to write the paths for stuff like CSS files, JS files, something like this:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseURL();?>/public/js/somejavascript.js></script>
```

And usually i use it when i need the base url (not only in layouts,also in views). I have been using the same helper in the 'default' module of the application and in the 'admin' module (modules/admin/...). Localy, everything went ok, no issues.
When i uploaded the project, i got errors like:

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

Message: Plugin by name 'BaseURL' was not found in the registry; used paths: Cmsadmin_View_Helper_: /path_to_site_like_public_html/application/modules/cmsadmin/views/helpers/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/
```

The error above was for a line using $this->baseURL() in the admin layout (which is called in the admin module).

At first i thought maybe because the helper is declared in another module (the default module), its not found by the framework in the admin module. But why locally everything works ? I dont get it. 
Also, if i change $this->baseURL() to $this->baseUrl() in the same admin.phtml layout file, in the admin module, everything works (online and locally).

If someone could enlighten me to whatever it is i am missing, i'd appreciate it.

P.S.: Since its not yet clear in my head, maybe someone could tell me : a helper declared in a module is available in all modules of the website? ( the local development told me it is, since its working locally, but then whats wrong with the uploaded project?).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check this

$this->baseUrl('');

keeping the parameter null may fix the problem.
you will get the baseurl in layout and also in default.php.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix your view helper with `Cmsadmin_View_Helper_` and not `Zend_View_Helper_` as described in the error message. The error message tells which paths it looks in for the various prefixes.

Comment: Two things i would like to mention:
1. I do have a helper in the cmsadmin module, and its named AdminBaseURL.php , and the code is:  

class Zend_View_Helper_AdminBaseURL
{
    function adminBaseURL()
    {
        $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        return $fc->getBaseUrl()."cmsadmin/";
    }
}

and 2. Still , why does it work when i use baseUrl() and not baseURL() in the state that things are now?

Comment: P.S. and a 3rd thing to mention: i also have another helper called class Zend_View_Helper_MediaDir in the same folder: cmsadmin/views/helpers , and that one works without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:-

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseURL();?>/public/js/somejavascript.js></script>
```

with:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/public/js/somejavascript.js></script>
```

not:- Always use `$this->baseUrl();`
its case sensitive